# How to Run AsyncTask at a certain time from a Activity?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask in a activity that i only want to run once a week. How do i go about doing this?

I am retrieving a list of URL's about 7 of them and then putting them in SharedPreference.

i only want to update and check for new URL's once a week from my activity. This will be in my Main Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the date when you use the asynctask in the shared preferences. 
So whenever the Main Activity starts you can check the current date and the date in the shared preferences, if its more than 7 days, you can do your asynctask again and update the saved date to the current date.

I believe you already know how to put strings inside shared preferences and to access them.

This is just the basic code of what to do. You will need to modify it a bit to get it working for you.

```
private static String getToday(){
    Calendar objCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone());
    DateFormat objFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    return objFormatter.format(objCalendar.getTime());
}

private static String getAfter7DaysDate(){
    Calendar objCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone());
    DateFormat objFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    objCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
    return objFormatter.format(objCalendar.getTime());
}

public int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
     return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

If you put this in the onCreate

```
    String today = getToday();
    String afterSevenDate = getAfter7DaysDate();

    DateFormat objFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    try {
        Log.e(today,Integer.toString(daysBetween(objFormatter.parse(today),
                objFormatter.parse(afterSevenDate))));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The above code just retrieves the current date, the date after 7 days, and also find the difference in days between the 2 dates. You will need to get the saved date and find the after 7 days date and check if the differnce between the current date is >= to 7. If its true, do your async task.

This is the simple way to do it.

As JoeLallouz mentioned this will only work if user goes to that activity. But it will work even if he opens after a month due to the >= checking. But if you need to do it even if the user doesn't open you're app, you will need to look into the AlarmManager class.

Comment: Good Idea! Could you provide just an example of how i would go about doing this?

Comment: I have my AsyncTask already created. Just how i would go about putting the date in SharedPreference. How i would check to see if it has been seven days, and then run each time the activity is opened?

Comment: This would assume that the User opens the main activity once per week, otherwise the async task would never fire. If you want it to happen, you should consider using AlarmManager class and a Service.

Comment: Well I went with the AlarmManager before? But could i have it pull the  date it last updated out of the preference. If its greater than todays current date by 7 then update...Wouldnt this work either way? And when it does update just put the current date it just updated into shared preference. Could you post in your code also if the user opens the actvity after 7 days how to test it for being pass seven days from the current date it pulled from the preference?

Comment: I could put days between the last update of the asynctask in  a shared preference and each time check to see if the current days between is less than equal to or greater..if greater or equal run the asynctask